# What's the problem with this mysql query in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a problem but i don't know where is a mistake?

```
private function getUsersPasswordByEmail($email){

        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT 'password' FROM 'user' WHERE 'email' = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($password);
        $stmt->fetch();
        return $password;}
```

error is in this line -

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
```

Details
Type: Error
Message: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApi\includes\DbOperations.php
Line: 63

Comment: What is this parameter called "s"? Where is it defined?

Comment: error means what? Please [edit] your question and add the complete error message!

Comment: @Abrikot "s" means it's a string

Comment: its may be `"SELECT password FROM user WHERE email = ?"`, why you are you using `single quotes` in name of columns and tablename

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Abrikot, it's string..

Comment: @ArtOsi > Right, I thought it was like PDO ('s' then had to be an identifier, not a type!).

Comment: @RakeshJakhar I first try without a quotes, but it's not working

Comment: What's the error message now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: Enable mysqli exceptions to see the errors.

Comment: @showdev now error is that password do not match, but i use good password...

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue. You might try debugging by outputting your variable values and see if they are what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `` ` `` backtick instead of `'` single quote

```
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT `password` FROM `user` WHERE `email` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
```

Comment: now error is
{
    "error": true,
    "message": "Invalid credential"
}
that means - password do not match, but i use good password

Comment: @MichaelDodd, I am using backtick ` instead of `'` in the query above

Comment: @RadenkoKozomara, Query is being executed. Now, there is nothing wrong with the code above. If its still bugging you, you need to ask another question

Comment: i think you're right, problem is in some other place... Thank you everyone!